# Cellular Homology and Arbitrary Coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

I'm trying to get the hang of working with homology with arbitrary coefficients. Given any abelian group $G$ and a topological space $X$, we can tensor the singular chain complex $\cdots \to C_{n+1}(X) \to C_n(X) \to C_{n-1}(X) \to \cdots$ with $G$ to obtain a chain complex
$$
\cdots \to C_{n+1}(X) \otimes G \to C_n(X) \otimes G \to C_{n-1}(X) \otimes G \to \cdots,
$$
and then we define the groups $H_n(X;G)$ as the homology of the above complex. But what if we started off with, say, the cellular chain complex for a CW-complex? The homology of that chain complex is the same as the homology of the above one, but will we get the same groups $H_n(X;G)$ if we tensor the cellular chain complex with $G$? More generally, is it true that different chain complexes give us the same homology with coefficients in $G$ if they have the same standard homology?

Comment: For your last question, you can take the chain complex $H_n$ with trivial differential to see that it's not true in general. I think you want a chain complex of free abelian groups quasi-isomorphic to singular chains.

Comment: Are you familiar with the universal coefficient theorem?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Just about to get to it but in the meantime I'd like to know if there's a more elementary way to see this.

Comment: Universal coefficient theorem is basically stating this, so it won’t get much more elementary.